# Anyone recognize this timestamp number format? 1590057793678624 (Hint: It's not unix time)

Tags: unix, time, timestamp, datetime-format

It doesn't seem to be unix time, since that would be in the year 50,388,895

I am receiving data from a product, and I assumed it was unix timestamp, but it's not.

Don't know where else to search.

Comment: What product? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: It's microseconds since the epoch. Just divide by one million (or cut off the last 6 digits) to get a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Current unix timestamp (as of 2020-07-21 11:30) is close to 1595323718 *when given in seconds*. If that number is supposed to represent a unix timestamp, it is just expressed in micro seconds. Just divide it with 1000000, to get a common timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

it is much easier to work with std::chrono instead

```
unsigned long long microseconds = std::stoull(microsecondsString);    //arriving timestamp in microseconds
std::chrono::microseconds microseconds_chrono(microseconds);
std::chrono::duration<double> seconds_chrono(microseconds_chrono);
double timestamp_seconds_double = seconds_chrono.count();
```

that's how I got the double needed

I wanted to find out how to convert a unix timestamp coming in as a string from microseconds, and into a double

std::chrono is really good, I am not going back

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be microseconds

The R&D team gave me this line of code

```
(measure::ConvertDuration<microseconds_d>(tpNs.time_since_epoch())).count();
```